# Pass pageTitle Nuxt / Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Hope you can help, Got three files, pages/about.vue, layouts/default.vue and components/Header.vue. Want to pass pageTitle from from about.vue so  inside components/Header.vue would show 'About us'. For future i also want to pass some dynamic data, for example total number of data retrieved from an API. Below is what I got so far, would appreciate help/assistance. Thanks.

Getting [Vue warn]: Property "pageTitle" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

```
<!-- components/header.vue --> 
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>            
    </div>
</template>

<!-- layouts/default.vue -->
<template>
    <div>
        <Header :pageTitle="pageTitle" />
        <slot />
        <Footer />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            pageTitle: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
}
</script>

<!-- pages/about.vue -->
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- about us -->
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    let pageTitle = "About us (dynamic value)";
</script>

// would like title to display number of users for example
let { data } = await supabase
   .from('profiles')
   .select(`username, website, avatar_url`)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1: Page title is fixed**

Use `definePageMeta`: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/define-page-meta

```
// pages/about.vue 

<script setup>
definePageMeta({
    title: "About Us",
})
</script>
```

```
// components/header.vue 

<script></script>
<template>
   <div>This is your header title {{ $route.meta.title }}</div>
</template>
```

**Solution 2: Page title is dynamic**

Use `useState`: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-state

`definePageMeta` is a macro and can't access component state so if you want to show the page title dynamically, can consider using Nuxt 3 `useState` instead:

```
// pages/about.vue 

<script setup>
let { data } = await supabase
   .from('profiles')
   .select(`username, website, avatar_url`)
const pageTitle = useState("pageTitle")
pageTitle.value = `About us (${data.count})`
</script>
```

```
// components/header.vue 

<script>
const pageTitle = useState("pageTitle")
</script>
<template>
   <div>This is your header title {{ pageTitle }}</div>
</template>
```

If you get the warning in console: `[Vue warn]: Hydration text mismatch:`, you can wrap the `<Header>` component with `<ClientOnly>` tag

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. I realised something and updated my question. Would appreciate some input there, its about showing dynamic value.

Comment: how about your dynamic value? It comes from async data, reactive data, or a calculation function?

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question. Thinking of using supabase to play around.

Comment: @devofash let try with my update

Comment: useState is only ran on the client, right? Wouldn't using this for SEO data be a bad idea? Since the data isn't there on page load.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible do this using provide/inject, see the documentation
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html

se the code below

about page, change for this

```
<script setup>
import { ref, provide } from 'vue';

const pageTitle = ref("About us");
provide('pageTitle', pageTitle);
</script>
```

and in layout

```
<script>
import Header from '~/components/Header.vue';
import Footer from '~/components/Footer.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        Header,
        Footer
    },
    inject: ['pageTitle']
}
</script>
```

header:

```
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        pageTitle: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but got - [Vue warn]: injection "pageTitle" not found and [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "pageTitle". Expected String with value "undefined", got Undefined

Comment: send me your code and i will fix this

Comment: Is this for both Nuxt2 and Nuxt3? Linked doc is Nuxt2.